# Cross Color Change Puzzle logical solution

Tags: colors, logic

I want to write a code that solve this puzzle for me.
The rules:

- If you click the **green** tile it becomes **red**.
- If you click the **red** tile it becomes **gray**.
- If you click the **gray** tile it becomes **green**.
- Also, if you click on a tile, it's neighbors vertically and horizontally also changes color, like a cross.
- You can click on a tile as many as you like.

For exmaple:

- [Click to view - If I click on the marked tile...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zP0v.jpg)
- [Click to view - It will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Cra.jpg)

I'm looking for a logic behind it, so far I have no clue. I can code that, it's not what I'm looking for, but the (mathematical?) logic behind the solution. For example, the Rubik's Cube steps to make to have a full ordered cube. I want to make a program that automatically tries to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple if you do this with an array,

```
int[][] box;

if(//if you click box[a][b])
{
    change_color(a,b);
    change_color(a-1,b);
    change_color(a+1,b);
    change_color(a,b-1);
    change_color(a,b+1);
}

change_color(int x,int y)
{
      if(box[x][y]==red)
      box[x][y]=grey;
      if(box[x][y]==grey)
      box[x][y]=green;
      if(box[x][y]==green)
      box[x][y]=red;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my queston was misleading. I can code that, it's not what I'm looking for, but the (mathematical?) logic behind the solution. For example, the Rubik's Cube steps to make to have a full ordered cube. I want to make a program that automatically tries to solve this.